# “Missing operating system” when booting from external HDD with Linux Mint

Tags: linux, hard-drive, usb, linux-mint

I installed Linux Mint 17.3 on an internal laptop HDD using a live USB stick. I now want to boot it externally on different PCs using a USB adapter. This works on the laptop I installed it on, but booting from this HDD on 2 desktop PCs I tried this with I get a black screen that just says "Missing operating system". Is this something I can fix, or do I need to install it differently?

Thanks.